# Interpolate a value from 2nd list based on value from first list

Tags: python

Let's say I have these two lists:

```
u_deteminer = [0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0, 1.2, 1.4, 1.6, 1.8, 2.0]
u_H = [0.368, 0.303, 0.301, 0.301, 0.301, 0.301, 0.301, 0.301, 0.301, 0.301]
```

I am given the value: `1.276819`.

The value at each index in `u_determiner` maps out to a value in `u_H` (e.g. 0.2 maps to 0.368). Using the given value, I would like to interpolate a value for `u_H`. Suggestions?

Comment: Do you have an idea of which interpolation method you'd want to use? FWIW, the value would just be `0.301`.

Comment: @Chris `1.27...` isn't an existing data point. Its image in `u_H` needs to be interpolated between the images of `1.2` and `1.4` in `u_H`.

Comment: Implement simple linear interpolation (or some other method).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numpy should make this easy.

```
import numpy as np
u_deteminer = [0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0, 1.2, 1.4, 1.6, 1.8, 2.0]
u_H = [0.368, 0.303, 0.301, 0.301, 0.301, 0.301, 0.301, 0.301, 0.301, 0.301]
np.interp(2.5, u_deteminer, u_H)
```

Output

```
0.301
```

Comment: `0.301` lol, what a shocker

Comment: Who would have thought :)

Comment: Why 2.5 though?

Comment: That was the value in the numpy documentation that I copy/pasted like the OP should have.

Comment: @Woj, that's the number you want to interpolate, change it to `1.276819` for your use case, although the answer will be the same.